# Using MTLS in real project

Tags: java, ssl

How to use MTLS in practice, using pure Java?
I've looked through several questions and answers on this subject, but I can't figure it out.

I have 2 certificates, ***my-service.cer*** and ***another-service.cer***

**The main question is how do I store and retrieve them properly?**

I'm thinking of using about the following code to retrieve

```
package com.wigravy.stackoverflow;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SecurityManager {

    private Properties getProperties() {
        // here I get property file from server directory
    }

    private KeyStore getKeyStore() {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("keystroke.jks")) {
            Properties properties = getProperties();
            char[] password = properties.getProperty("keystore.password").toCharArray();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
            keyStore.load(fis, password);
            return keyStore;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Something going wrong");
    }

    public KeyManager[] getKeyManager() {
        try {
            Properties properties = getProperties();
            char[] password = properties.getProperty("keystore.password").toCharArray();
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(getKeyStore(), password);
            return keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Something going wrong");
    }

    public TrustManager[] getTrustManager() {
        try {
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init(getKeyStore());
            return trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Something going wrong");
    }
}
```

The **keystroke.jks** file here is a separately created storage for these 2 certificates (I don't know if I need to do this yet). Maybe it makes sense to encode it in BASE64 to the properties file, store the password in encrypted form and decrypt it on the application side.

Comment: Are you the server or the client in this exchange, you will also need the private key associated with the certificate you present in the exhange.

Comment: @PaulWhelan This is an exchange between two services and verification is done on both sides, I have a private key for my-service.cert

Comment: Are you the client or the server for the service - have you tried https://dzone.com/articles/hakky54mutual-tls-1